# Chrome Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded click recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery custom function. The 'uncheck all' and 'check all' functions do what they say. However when I click on an individual checkbox I get the Maximum call stack size exceeded error. I have hit a brick wall testing where the recursion is occurring. Please advise. Thank you

```
$.fn.multiselect = function(fn, options) {
    if (typeof fn === 'object') {
        options = fn;
        fn = 'init';
    }
    if (typeof fn === 'undefined') {
        fn = 'init';
    }
    //return direct methods
    var directMethods = {
        'widget': function() {
            return  $(this).data('multiselect-widget');
        },
        'modal': function() {
            return  $(this).data('multiselect-modal');
        }
    };
    var args = arguments;
    Array.prototype.shift.call(args);
    if (args.length > 0) {
        args.shift();
    }
    if (typeof directMethods[fn] === 'function') {
        return directMethods[fn].apply(this, args);
    }

    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var config = $.extend({}, {}, options || {
                list: 1,
                body: 'body'
            }, $(this).data());
            var $$ = $(this).hide();
            $$.data('multiselect', config);
            var $div = $('<div class="input-append dropdown-multiselect">').insertAfter($$);
            $$.data('multiselect-widget', $div);
            var $span = $('<span class="input-xlarge uneditable-input label" />').appendTo($div);
            var $btn = $('<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></span>').appendTo($div);
            var $modal = $('<div class="modal hide fade modal-multiselect" />')
                    .appendTo($(config.body));
            if ($$.attr('id')) {
                $modal.attr('id', 'modal-multiselect-' + $$.attr('id'));
            }
            $div.click(function() {
                $modal.modal('show');
            });
            $$.data('multiselect-modal', $modal);
            var $menu = $('<div class="modal-body" role="multiselect" />').appendTo($modal);
            var $controls = $('<div class="modal-footer" role="multiselectcontrols" />').appendTo($modal);
            $("<span>").addClass('btn')
                    .appendTo($controls)
                    .text('Close')
                    .click(function() {
                        $modal.modal('hide');
                    });
            if ($$.attr('multiple')) {
                $controls.append($("<span class='btn btn-mini pull-left'>").html('<i class="icon-check-empty"></i>uncheck all').click(function() {
                    $$.val('');
                    $menu.find(":checkbox").prop('checked', false);
                    $$.multiselect('refreshLabel');
                }));
                $controls.append($("<span class='btn btn-mini pull-left'>").html('<i class="icon-check"></i>check all').click(function() {
                    $menu.find(":checkbox").prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked")).each(function() {
                        $(this).trigger('click');
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    });
                }));
            }
            $$.multiselect('refresh');
        },
        refresh: function() {
            var $menu = $(this).multiselect('modal').find('[role=multiselect]').empty();
            var $controls = $(this).multiselect('modal').find('[role=multiselectcontrols]');
            var $$ = $(this);
            var val = $$.val();
            var type = ($$.attr('multiple')) ? 'checkbox' : 'radio';
            var clickIn = function() {
                var check = $(this).is(":checked");
                var self = this;
                if ($$.attr('multiple')) {
                    var values = $$.val() || [];
                    if (check) {
                        values.push($(this).val());
                    } else {
                        values.splice($.inArray($(this).val(), values), 1);
                    }
                    $$.val(values).multiselect('refreshLabel').trigger('change');
                } else {
                    $menu.find("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
                        if (this !== self) {
                            $(this).prop('checked', false);
                        }
                    });
                    $$.multiselect('modal').modal('hide');
                    $$.val($(this).val()).multiselect('refreshLabel').trigger('change');
                }
                return $(this);
            };
            var $lastParent = $$;
            var $appendTo = $('<ul class="multiselect-menu">').appendTo($menu);
            var $optGroup = null;
            $$.find('option').each(function() {
                if ($(this).parent().is($lastParent) === false) {
                    $lastParent = $(this).parent();
                    if ($lastParent.is('optgroup')) {
                        $optGroup = $('<li>').append($('<label class="optgroup">').text($lastParent.attr('label')));
                    }
                }

                if ($optGroup !== null) {
                    $($optGroup).append(
                            $("<ul>").append($("<li>").append($('<label>').append(
                            $('<input type="' + type + '">')
                            .attr({
                                checked: (typeof val === 'string') ? val === $(this).val() : $.inArray($(this).val(), val) > -1,
                                value: $(this).val()
                            })
                            .click(function() {
                                clickIn.apply(this);
                            })
                            )
                            .append($(this).text()))));
                    $($optGroup).appendTo($appendTo);
                }

                if ($optGroup === null) {
                    $("<li>").appendTo($appendTo)
                            .append($('<label>')
                                    .append(
                                            $('<input type="' + type + '">')
                                            .attr({
                                                checked: (typeof val === 'string') ? val === $(this).val() : $.inArray($(this).val(), val) > -1,
                                                value: $(this).val()
                                            })
                                            .click(function() {
                                                clickIn.apply(this);
                                            })
                                            )
                                    .append($(this).text()));
                }
            });
            $$.multiselect('refreshLabel');
        },
        refreshLabel: function() {
            var self = this;
            var $$ = $(this).multiselect('widget');
            var txt = '';
            var options = $(this).data('multiselect');
            var val = $(this).val() || [];
            if (typeof val === 'string') {
                txt = $(this).find('[value="' + val + '"]').text();
            } else {
                var len = (val) ? val.length : 0;
                if (len > options.list || len === 0) {
                    txt = len + ' of ' + $(this).find('option').length + ' selected';
                } else {
                    var texts = [];
                    $.each(val, function(index, v) {
                       texts.push($(self).find('[value=' + v + ']').text());
                    });
                    txt = texts.join(', ');
                }
            }
            $$.find('.label').text(txt);
        }
    };
    return $(this).each(function() {
        methods[fn].apply(this, args);
    });

};
```

The call stack is:

```
jQuery.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
jQuery.extend.each
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)
e.fn.extend.focus
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatch
elemData.handle.eventHandle
jQuery.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
jQuery.extend.each
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)
e.fn.extend.focus
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatch
elemData.handle.eventHandle
jQuery.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
jQuery.extend.each
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)
e.fn.extend.focus
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatch
elemData.handle.eventHandle
jQuery.event.trigger
(anonymous function)
jQuery.extend.each
etc..
```

Comment: Your focus event appears to be hitting $(someele).each() which is triggering a focus event, which then repeats the process. Though, i don't see it in your code (there's just SO much code there...), so basically for some reason when you focus the element, the focus event is being triggered again on it causing an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the code somewhere so you can see where the recursion is happening?  That's a complicated plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you wrap checkboxes into `<label>` tag. This causes same error in my case. So you can put your checkboxes like this:

```
<label for="checkbox-1">Some label</label>
<input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox-1">
```